# How to upload ipa file to Dropbox using fastlane and circleci?

Tags: ios, dropbox, ipa, circleci, fastlane

I want to use FastLane to upload the IPA file to Dropbox. I follow the Dropbox documentation: https://github.com/tommy071/fastlane-plugin-publish_dropbox and the Circleci has run successfully, but I can't find the IPA file in my dropbox catalog.

The code is as follows:

```
- run: bundle exec fastlane add_plugin publish_dropbox

publish_dropbox(
    file_path: '/Users/distiller/project/output/gym/xxx.ipa',
    dropbox_path: 'https://www.dropbox.com/home/xxx%20xxx%20xx%20Folder/Development/xxx-IOS',
    app_key: 'xxxxxx',
    app_secret: 'xxxxx'
  )
```

The progress of circleci is as follows:

[image]

In addition, I noticed that there is a dropbox document here. I don't know if it is useful. Should I add my project?

Dropbox document: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift

Comment: I have no idea about it but you should upload IPA on https://www.diawi.com/.

Comment: Thank you, Dropbox is where we store the files, so we want to upload the app's IPA file to the dropbox after the gym command.

Comment: Got a feeling that `https://www.dropbox.com` might not be needed in the path, instead just use the path within dropbox itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer, it does not work, I used another Fastlane plugin 'dropbox', these look great and the prompt "Starting upload of /Users/distiller/project/output/gym/Carepilot.ipa to Dropbox", but finally failed, prompt " No value found for 'password' ". please see it link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234266/how-to-solve-the-failure-of-uploading-ios-ipa-file-to-dropbox-using-fastlane-and.

Comment: As mentioned before `dropbox_path ` is probably meant to be used in a different way. But as the docs even say it is optional (`The dropbox_path parameter is optional - if not provided, the file at file_path would be put in the Dropbox root directory.`) so maybe just leave that out and see if it uploads to the Dropbox root first before trying other things.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-upload-iOS-ipa-file-to-Dropbox-using-fastlane-and/m-p/334603 ]

Comment: Did you solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The token created from your api key and secret is stored in the keychain. You need to either pass the `keychain_password` or set the `DROPBOX_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD` environment variable.

In CircleCI, the keychain password is an empty string unless you changed it in the `setup_circle_ci` action.

As the docs say:

> If not provided, the plugin would ask for password

But the plug-in can’t ask in CI because the terminal is not interactive.